# Objective-C: App-wide fully reusable custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Hi, this question has been asked many times however I was never able to find a proper solution for the following:

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which shows the user profile picture and a 'Follow'/'Following' button. I reuse this cell in around 10 `UIViewControllers`/`UITableViewControllers` throughout the app.

Now to my question: Adding the 'Following' button action logic (i.e. a server call to follow or unfollow the user) in the `UITableViewCell` class would be against MVC so I currently add the action to the button in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and call the necessary code inside the `UIViewController` action method e.g. `- (void)followUnfollowUser:(id)sender`. 
(The actual server call is in an external class with static methods but the call to this is still in the `followUnfollowUser:(id)sender` method)

What this means is every time I need to use the custom `UITableViewCell` I need to add this code to the controller. Except for the UI logic (which is allowed in the `UITableViewCell` class) I don't see any reuse. Why should an action related to the `UITableViewCell` be in the `UIViewController`? Is there a way I can just reuse the custom `UITableViewCell` without having to rewrite the follow/unfollow action?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the button inside a cell and handle the action there.
From view controller that creates a cell all you need to do is to call some kind of model update on your custom cell - that will allow cell to call API directly from inside - or whatever is action doing in your application can be coded directly inside custom cell class.

If you need any feedback to UIViewController to reload view or smth - add either a delegate that will be called when user click on those elements or use NSNotificationCenter for that purpose.

Comment: I understand the `delegate` or `NSNotification` bits you mention. What I don't understand is _"From outside all you need to do is to call some kind of model update on your custom cell - that will allow cell to call API directly from inside."_  could you please elaborate?

Comment: So if I understood well, what you are saying is I can code the action (which invokes the API call) inside the `UITableViewCell` but attach the action in the ViewController `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as follows:   `[cell.btnFollowUnfollow addTarget:cell action:@selector(followUnfollowAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` where `followUnfollowAction:` would be a method in the `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: ...and should I need to pass any messages to the `ViewController` I'd then use the delegate or notifications.

Comment: Excatly. I expect you do some server API call with updates to unfollow user - you can implement API call inside custom cell and on success handler from API call, you can call delegate method to reload viewController

Comment: Ok great, one last thing and I'm marking your answer. Will I have issues with deallocated `UITableViewCell` i.e. If I scroll the cell off the screen while the API call is running how will I get onComplete call for the deallocated cell?

Comment: It depends how you do it there :) If you have your API using blocks, you can always keep reference to most important variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Delegate` or `Block`

Create a property and assign the code from the View Controller, then run on the button click run it

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^loginCompletionBlock)(BOOL);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^inviteBlock)(NSDictionary*result);

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender{
    if(self.inviteBlock){
        self.inviteBlock(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this answers my question. My problem is not calling the action, my problem is reuse and avoiding the need to stay declaring the action each time. Including the follow/unfollow logic in the `UITableViewCell` is against MVC rules

Comment: Creating a block for every single cell is not best idea